# Fill parent width equally

Tags: html, css

I have a container width some buttons in it:

```
<div class="button-container">
        <button type="button" class="edit-quantity">Edit Quantity</button>
        <button type="button" class="edit-price">Edit Price</button>
        <button type="button" class="remove-item">Remove</button>
        <button type="button" class="remove-all">Remove All</button>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gRzAB/

How can I style the buttons and the container in a way that the buttons fill the container width equally, even if there is just 1 or 2 or 3 buttons?

Comment: a CSS3 only solution is acceptable? Which browser do you need to support?

Comment: @RGraham Yup, that's the solution I was going to answer but looks like its been covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display:table;` and `display:table-cell;` if you add a wrapping div around your buttons :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/gRzAB/1/)**

*HTML :*

```
<div class="button-container">
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="edit-quantity">...</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="edit-price">...</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="remove-item">...</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="remove-all">...</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
.button-container {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    display:table;
}
.button-container >div {
    display:table-cell;
}
.button-container button {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `display: flex` from CSS3: [Check my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kulakkulak/gZg4w/1/).

```
.button-container{
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
}

.button-container button{
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Using flex box layout is very perspective, in future we can use this kind of layout without worrying about the support, but now there are still many browsers (almost the old versions) lacking support of this layout...

Comment: This seems to work, but I'm not sure if it is supported by all browsers... Thanks!

Comment: @amp On desktops IE<10 seems to be the only problem.